# Cannot find symbol - constructor JAVA

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

I'm getting the error cannot find symbol - constructor Customer whilst trying to set up this class.

```
public class PersonalCustomer extends Customer
{   
    public PersonalCustomer(String accountNumber, Address address, Name name)
    {
        super(accountNumber, address);
        name = name;        
    }
}
```

Below is the class Customer.

```
public abstract class Customer
{    
    private String accountNumber;
    private Address address;
    private int balance;
    private char customerType;

    public Customer(String accountNumber, Address address, char customerType)
    {
        accountNumber = "";
        address = address;
        balance = 0;
        customerType = ' ';
    }
```

Can anyone help as too where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 7):

`Customer` constructor is declared with three arguments:

```
public Customer(String accountNumber, Address address, char customerType)
```

while call from child class only provides two:

```
super(accountNumber, address);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm now getting the error customerType has private access in Customer. The spec asks that customer type be either 'B' or 'P' representing Personal Customer or business customer, any additional help?

Comment: It's a constructor for `PersonalCustomer` so I assume you can just pass 'P' as a third argument, like: `super(accountNumber, address, 'P');`. I guess you should pass 'B' if you're going to implement `BusinessCustomer` class in the same manner.

Answer (score 2):

`super(accountNumber, address, CustomerType);`

Java compiler is trying to find the `super()` constructor with 2 arguments, which unfortunately does not exist. Bails out with an error!

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to `Customer`'s constructor signature, it has 3 parameters.

Now, you're calling it from `PersonalCustomer`'s constructor providing only 2.